# Copy data between two values - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to VBA and I have been trying to work out how to do the below for a while now, any help really appreciated!

I have a row of data that looks like this (but much longer!)

**30** 456 789 489 384 **30** 2789 394 3827 2783 382 **30** 488 3773 37773 27722 **30**

Each **30** represents what should be a new line and therefore I would like to copy the data between each **30** to a new row.

The issue is I haven't been able to work out how to select just the data range between the the **30**s to copy.

I have tried various things but I have had no luck!

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Start from here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/266289 . You can add a space before and after the string and then use ` 30 ` as a delimiter.

Comment: After you did what was mentioned above you will probably have everything in one row. Then you need to transpose the output you get to have it on all different rows.

Comment: "I have tried various things" - what have you tried? Do you have an example of your code so far? Also - would you consider a non-VBA solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub setRows()
    Dim raw As String, xLns As Variant, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, xArr As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    raw = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(ws.UsedRange.Rows(1))), "|")
    xLns = Split(raw, "30|")
    For i = 0 To UBound(xLns)
        If Len(xLns(i)) > 0 Then
            xArr = Split(xLns(i), "|")
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(i + 1, 1), ws.Cells(i + 1, UBound(xArr))) = xArr
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```